# Iphone-App Freezes for some time

Tags: iphone

When I am clicking on the application icon, the app freezes for some time and is not opened. No crash report is generated.

From the console logs I could get the following warning:

```
Jun  6 10:55:00 Saschas-iPhone UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: TRACE: <MBConnection: 0x160790> connection interrupted

Jun  6 10:55:00 Saschas-iPhone UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: DEBUG: <MBConnection: 0x160790> disconnected

Jun  6 10:55:00 Saschas-iPhone UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: TRACE: Canceling <MBConnection: 0x160790>

Jun  6 10:55:00 Saschas-iPhone UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: TRACE: <MBConnection: 0x160790> connection invalid
```

Would the above mentioned warnings have caused any affect to the application.

Kindly let me know what the warnings mean.

Answer (score 1):

use splash screen and add breakpoint into

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

And then check where is the problem....